# Can anyone explain this behavior?

Tags: dart

I accidentally came across this behavior while playing around the async behavior.

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6cac2e240375b531630c9e47e3875b63

Can anyone explain to me why the setTimeout with 0 seconds is not executing the print statement immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` enqueues the passed function into the event queue and the passed code is executed async. https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop

The sync code is executed to the end and then the next event in the event queue is processed.

Comment: Interesting. I also noticed that this behavior does not occur when you use
Future.sync instead of setTimeout

Comment: `Future`s have a bit different behavior. There is also the microtask queue, which is processed before the next task from the event queue is executed. `Future` has even higher precedence AFAIR.

Comment: Re: 'sync code is executed to the end'. 'End' means the end of the current function, or `yield` is called (if in a sync* or async* function), right ?

Comment: "sync code is executed to the end" means that all sync code that was invoked by an event handler (first task from the event queue got invoked) is executed until this call returned. All sync code and sync function calls made from within this event handler and from within functions called from this event handler are executed until they return. All async calls made somewhere from this sync code are added to the event queue (or microtask queue) for later execution.